# PHP intl на Mac OSX Sierra 10.13.4

Tags: php, composer

При выполнении команды

```
composer install --prefer-dist
```

возникает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю что нужно установить php intl, пробую командой

```
brew install php71-intl
```

Получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же пробовал переустановить php но ошибка всё так же остаётся.
Может кто-то подскажет как исправить?

Comment: Такая же проблема! Если автор ее решил, то поделитесь, пожалуйста ответом

Comment: @AlisaZhuryk помоему проблема была с версией php, нужно ставить стабильную версию